# MissingMethodException after upgrading to Monotouch 4.0

Tags: c#, iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Does anyone use the excellent Sparrow 2D monotouch library?

https://github.com/trustme/Sparrow

I just updated to Monotouch 4.0 and Monodevelop 2.4.2, and when
rebuilt and run SparrowTest gives me this strange error:

```
System.MissingMethodException has been thrown "Method not found:
'Monotouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_Boolean'." at
SparrowTest.AppDelegateIPhone.FinishedLaunching in
AppDelegateIPhone.cs:23
```

The method is:

```
SPStage.SupportHighResolutions = true;
```

When commented it gives the same error on many other methods. I've
tried using different sdk versions but the problem persists.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You need to regenerate the sparrow.dll with btouch for MonoTouch 4.

Comment: I tried to regenerate the sparrow.dll from the sparrow.cs included in the archive. In my terminal I typed: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch -o sparrow.dll sparrow.cs But unfortunatlely it returns me some errors: sparrow.cs(123,120): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SPHAlign' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
sparrow.cs(123,137): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `SPVAlign' could not be found. ...Compilation failed: 9 error(s), 0 warnings
btouch: API binding contains errors.

Comment: I think I've incurred in this bug: 
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=662903  


$ /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch sparrow.cs -s:enum.cs extensions.cs
sparrow.cs(140,11): error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type `Sparrow.SPButton'. Another partial declaration of this type exists
extensions.cs(8,30): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
...
sparrow.cs(464,11): error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type `Sparrow.SPEventDispatcher'. 
Compilation failed: 10 error(s), 0 warnings
btouch: API binding contains errors.

Answer (score 0):

try to  create a script with -out  to regenerate Third Part Libraries
another way to avoid this problem, is that inm your build output of your project choose : Don't link the assemblies 
and your project will work

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

With MonoTouch 4.0 we must use smcs instead of gmcs.

Here is the right procedure for generating sparrow.dll with MonoTouch 4.0, in two steps:

/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch sparrow.cs -s:enum.cs --outdir=gen -ns=Sparrow --unsafe --sourceonly=genfiles

/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs -out:sparrow.dll `cat genfiles` extensions.cs  -unsafe -r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll enum.cs -target:library

Thanks to Geoff Norton and Duane Wandless for the help!